# TinyMCE Menu Button Icon Doesn't Appear

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I'm trying to create TinyMCE Menu Button which should open multiple popup window manager. It works fine but the button image doesn't appear.

here is the code. Am I doing something wrong?

```
(function() {  
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.shortcodes', {  
        init : function(ed, url) {  

            ed.addCommand('scTypography', function() {
                ed.windowManager.open({
                        file : url + '/dialog.htm',
                        width : 800 + ed.getLang('example.delta_width', 0),
                        height : 500 + ed.getLang('example.delta_height', 0),
                        inline : 1
                });
            });

            ed.addCommand('scColumns', function() {
                ed.windowManager.open({
                        file : url + '/dialog.htm',
                        width : 800 + ed.getLang('example.delta_width', 0),
                        height : 500 + ed.getLang('example.delta_height', 0),
                        inline : 1
                });
            });

            ed.addCommand('scButtons', function() {
                ed.windowManager.open({
                        file : url + '/dialog.htm',
                        width : 800 + ed.getLang('example.delta_width', 0),
                        height : 500 + ed.getLang('example.delta_height', 0),
                        inline : 1
                });
            });
        },  


        createControl : function(n, cm) {  
            switch (n) {
                case 'shortcodes':
                    var c = cm.createMenuButton('shortcodes', {
                        title : 'My menu button',
                        image : '/btn.png'
                    });

                    c.onRenderMenu.add(function(c, m) {
                        var sub;

                        sub = m.addMenu({title : 'Some item 3'});

                        sub.add({title : 'Typography', onclick : function() {
                                tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('scTypography');
                        }});

                        sub.add({title : 'Layout Columns', onclick : function() {
                                tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('scColumns');
                        }});

                        sub.add({title : 'Buttons', onclick : function() {
                                tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('scButtons');
                        }});

                    });

                    // Return the new menu button instance
                    return c;
            }
            return null;  
        },  

    });  
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('shortcodes', tinymce.plugins.shortcodes);  
})();
```

I'm not dev, but trying to understand this part to use in Wordpress theme.
Any one can help please?

Comment: I figured out that I need to put the absolute url to work. Any other idea?

Answer (score 2):

While the URL to the toolbar image is absolute, you can use the value of the url supplied in *init()* function that is the URL to the plugin location. For example

```
image : url + '/btn.png'
```

Comment: When I tried that, the editor toolbar crashed. here is a screenshot... http://awesomescreenshot.com/07fgvssc9

When I tried that with addButton, it works. Looks like I do something wrong

Comment: I'd guess the problem is that the url variable is available in the init() function, but not in the createControl() function, so you will need to store it (or the calculated button image url) in a variable within your plugin in the init() so it can be used in the createControl().

Comment: Exactly, but I couldn't figure out how to do this. Can you show me the needed code line and where to insert it?

Answer (score 0):

Additional to Bretts answer you may need to put the button explicitly into the button config part of the tinymce init.

**Example:**

I added my own ßplugins buttons to the tinymce UI using this code onInit in my own plugins:

```
// Register my_button
ed.addButton('my_button', {
  title : 'Click me!',
  cmd :   'my_command',
  image : url + "my_image.png";
});
```

and here the relevant part of the tinymce init

```
theme_advanced_buttons1:"style,bold,italic,underline",
theme_advanced_buttons2: "cleanup,save,preview,my_button", // <-- here
```

Comment: This works when I use addButton, I'm using here createMenueButton, looks like it works in different way, or what?!

Comment: i never used createMenueButton, but i guess there is a different way. did you have alook at the tinymce examples on the moxiecode page? - maybe there you are able to find what you need